# Bind Items to MenuItem -> use Command

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, menu, menuitem

I have a MenuItem, which has a collection of items in it. It looks like the File -> Open Menuitem.

So:

- File

  - Open

    - Open from DataBase

      - File 1
      - File 2
      - File 3

XAML Code:

```
<Menu>
<MenuItem Header="File">
    <MenuItem Header="Open">
        <MenuItem Header="From Database" ItemsSource="{Binding OCFragebogen}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

I want to call a Command, when a specific item has been clicked. Example: User clicks on File 1, a command should be called where the "File 1" is the Command Parameter.

ViewModel contains the Items, which I want to display in the MenuItem "collection"

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _OCFragebogen;
public ObservableCollection<string> OCFragebogen
{
    get
    {
        if (_OCFragebogen == null)
            _OCFragebogen = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        return _OCFragebogen;
    }
    set
    {
        _OCFragebogen = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => OCFragebogen);
    }
}
```

To make it clear: When the user clicks on an item (from the ItemsSource) in the MenuItem, a Command should be called where I want to do something with the clicked Item.

Edit: Where do I have to use the command to call a method (RelayCommand) in my ViewModel? I want it to be used when an Item from the ItemsSource has been clicked + I want to pass the clicked item to the method.

Comment: And your question / issue is?

Comment: I don't know where I have to use the Command and how I can pass the clicked item to the command by using `CommandParameter`. I'm currently using the `Command` in the MenuItem with the Header "From Database", but it won't call the command, since I click on the Item from the ItemsSource.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you

```
<MenuItem Header="From Database" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemSource}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=MenuItem}, Path=DataContext.YourCommandName}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"></Setter>
         </Style>
     </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to change its ItemContainerStyle and then bind the command from ItemsSource item,

```
<MenuItem Header="From Database" ItemsSource="{Binding OCFragebogen}"
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
  <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding YourCommand}" />
  </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
</MenuItem>
```

I haven't tried if it works just a guess

edited answer

```
                <MenuItem Header="From Database" ItemsSource="{Binding OCFragebogen}">
                    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}, Path=DataContext.YourCommand }" />
                            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Path=Header}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </MenuItem>
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, but it doesn't work. The Command is not being called + I still need to pass the clicked item to my called Command.

Comment: Ahh now I understand a bit more. I thought you had ItemsSource of all menuitems and each menuitem has its own command. But this is not the case, menuitem is a collection but each has same action but different parameter. Can you please clarify?

Comment: that's totally right. The MenuItem contains a ItemsSource. Each Item should call the same command, but with a different parameter (the parameter should be the item itself), so I can handle the clicked item. It looks kinda like this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DynamicMenus/DynamicMenus.jpg

Comment: We can try to bind the command to a relative source. Lets say that the command you want to bind to is at the same level of your ItemsSource i.e. OCFragebogen lets name it YourCommand so <Setter Property="Command", Value ="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}, Path=ItemsSource.YourCommand}" />

Comment: Thanks for helping, but Nitesh was faster. Anyway, voted up your answer, since I can only allow 1 answer to be correct.