# MenuItem Passing selected item to ViewModel via RelayCommand ala MVVM-Light & Header

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, contextmenu

I've been working off of this Q/A and a bunch of others to try and figure this out, but I must be missing something simple:
[Bind Items to MenuItem -> use Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17830587/bind-items-to-menuitem-use-command)

I created this little test application to try and understand context menus and learn about how to wire up the click events to relay commands in the ViewModel, and get access to the currently selected item from the context menu.

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenuTest_01.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="105" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContextMenuTest_01.ViewModels"
    DataContext="MainWindowViewModel">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MainWindowViewModel" ObjectType="{x:Type local:MainWindowViewModel}" IsAsynchronous="True"/>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- CONTEXT MENU -->
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu DataContext="MainWindowViewModel" Name="MainWindowContextMenu" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High">
        <MenuItem Header="Skins" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}, Path=Skins}">
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}, Path=Skins.SkinName}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}, Path=ContextMenuClickCommand}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SkinName}"/>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
using ContextMenuTest_01.Models;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using ContextMenuTest_01.CommandBase;
using System.Windows;

namespace ContextMenuTest_01.ViewModels
{
/// <summary>Main Window View Model</summary>
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    #region Class Variables
    /// <summary>The skins</summary>
    private ObservableCollection<SkinItem> skins = new ObservableCollection<SkinItem>();
    #endregion Class Variables

    public RelayCommand<object> ContextMenuClickCommand{ get; private set; }

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>Gets the skins.</summary>
    /// <value>The skins.</value>
    public ObservableCollection<SkinItem> Skins
    {
        get { return this.skins; }
        private set { this.skins = value; }
    }
    #endregion Properties

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindowViewModel"/> class.</summary>
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ContextMenuClickCommand = new RelayCommand<object>((e) => OnMenuItemClick(e));

        skins.Add(new SkinItem("Skin Item 1"));
        skins.Add(new SkinItem("Skin Item 2"));
        skins.Add(new SkinItem("Skin Item 3"));
    }

    /// <summary>Called when [menu item click].</summary>
    public void OnMenuItemClick(object selected)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Got to the ViewModel! YAY!!!");
    }
}
}
```

So the function OnMenuItemClick will get hit in the debugger and the message box is shown if I change the following three lines in the ViewModel:

Remove the  from the Relay Command definition:

```
public RelayCommand ContextMenuClickCommand{ get; private set; }
```

Remove the  and (e) from where the RelayCommand is created:

```
ContextMenuClickCommand = new RelayCommand(() => OnMenuItemClick());
```

Remove the (object selected) from the OnMenuItemClick public function:

```
public void OnMenuItemClick()
```

Then everything works but of course I don't have the currently selected item.
So what am I missing in the XAML that would command parameter from passing the argument SkinName to the RelayCommand?

Also if I leave off the line:

```
<Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}, Path=Skins.SkinName}"/>
```

Then I get the following in my context menu:

```
     Skins -> ContextMenuTest_01.Models.SkinItem

              ContextMenuTest_01.Models.SkinItem

              ContextMenuTest_01.Models.SkinItem
```

Which tells me the binding is working correctly, it's just not displaying it correctly, which is why I tried to insert  the

```
<Setter Property="Header"....
```

but of course that's not working as I would expect it to.

Thanks for your time! Any ideas would be helpful!

I don't have anything in the code behind which is the way it should be when following MVVM.
Here is my skinItem class, not much to speak of, but I figured I would show it before someone asks about it:

```
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ContextMenuTest_01.Models
{
/// <summary>A small data structure to hold a single skin item.</summary>
public class SkinItem
{
    #region Class Variables
    /// <summary>The skin name</summary>
    private string skinName;
    /// <summary>The base skin name</summary>
    private string baseSkinName;
    /// <summary>The skin path</summary>
    private string skinPath;
    /// <summary>The action to be taken when switching skins.</summary>
    private ICommand action;
    /// <summary>The icon of the skin.</summary>
    private Brush icon;
    #endregion Class Variables

    #region Constructors
    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SkinItem"/> class.</summary>
    public SkinItem() { }

    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SkinItem" /> class.</summary>
    /// <param name="newSkinName">The name of the new skin.</param>
    /// <param name="baseSkinName">Name of the base skin.</param>
    /// <param name="newSkinPath">Optional Parameter: The new skin path.</param>
    /// <param name="newSkinAction">Optional Parameter: The new skin action to be taken when switching to the new skin.</param>
    /// <param name="newSkinIcon">Optional Parameter: The new skin icon.</param>
    public SkinItem(string newSkinName, string baseSkinName = "", string newSkinPath = "", ICommand newSkinAction = null, Brush newSkinIcon = null)
    {
        if (newSkinName != "")
            this.skinName = newSkinName;

        if (baseSkinName != "")
            this.baseSkinName = baseSkinName;

        if (newSkinPath != "")
            this.skinPath = newSkinPath;

        if (newSkinAction != null)
            this.action = newSkinAction;

        if (newSkinIcon != null)
            this.icon = newSkinIcon;
    }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties
    /// <summary>Gets or sets the name of the skin.</summary>
    /// <value>The name of the skin.</value>
    public string SkinName
    {
        get { return this.skinName; }
        set
        {
            if (this.skinName != value)
            {
                this.skinName = value;
                //OnPropertyChanged(() => this.SkinName);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the name of the base skin.</summary>
    /// <value>The name of the base skin.</value>
    public string BaseSkinName
    {
        get { return this.baseSkinName; }
        set
        {
            if (this.baseSkinName != value)
            {
                this.baseSkinName = value;
                //OnPropertyChanged(() => this.BaseSkinName);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the skin path.</summary>
    /// <value>The skin path.</value>
    public string SkinPath
    {
        get { return this.skinPath; }
        set
        {
            if (this.skinPath != value)
            {
                this.skinPath = value;
                //OnPropertyChanged(() => this.SkinPath);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the action.</summary>
    /// <value>The action.</value>
    public ICommand Action
    {
        get { return this.action; }
        set
        {
            if (this.action != value)
            {
                this.action = value;
                //OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Action);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>Gets or sets the icon.</summary>
    /// <value>The icon.</value>
    public Brush Icon
    {
        get { return this.icon; }
        set
        {
            if (this.icon != value)
            {
                this.icon = value;
                //OnPropertyChanged(() => this.Icon);
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion Properties
}
}
```

Oh and I am using Galasoft MVVM-Light generic RelayCommand which is supposed to take parameters, can be found here:
http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Command/RelayCommandGeneric.cs

Comment: So is the problem that the SkinName is not showing in the context menu?

Comment: Yes, and also that I cannot send a command parameter to the relayCommand. So it's really a two-part problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly what you're looking for.  But in running your code I see that the names of the Skins are not showing in the context menu.  If you remove the source so your setting looks like this for the header:

```
<!-- CONTEXT MENU -->
<Window.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu DataContext="MainWindowViewModel" Name="MainWindowContextMenu" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High">
        <MenuItem Header="Skins" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}, Path=Skins}">
            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=SkinName}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}, Path=ContextMenuClickCommand}"/>
                    <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=SkinName}"/>
                </Style>
            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        </MenuItem>
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.ContextMenu>
```

That will fix your problem.  Since you are setting the source on the MenuItem, you change the datacontext for the items within.  So you don't need to specify the source again.

Edit:

Also I changed the Path from Skins.SkinName to SkinName

Now I see the text for the items in the menu and when I click on say "Skin Item 1", the value of selected in OnMenuItemClick is "Skin Item 1".

Comment: I said that removing it would get some data to display, but it just displays ContextMenuTest_01.Models.SkinItem not the actual name, which is why I was trying to add this header property, and this doesn't fix the problem with the Command Parameter getting sent to the RelayCommand.

Comment: In my testing, all I had to change was that, and my menu items show Skin Item 1, Skin Item 2, and Skin Item 3

Comment: Oops, also I forget to mention that I changed the Path from Skins.SkinName to SkinName

Comment: I did try that and the context menu shows 3 rows, but they are all empty for me, and the relay command is never fired. Wait your talking about changing the Setter Property="Header" Path=Skins to Path=SkinName? or <MenuItem Header="Skins" Path="Skins"? Well if the former, then yea, I got 3 empty rows, and no command getting fired. If the latter than I don't have anything at all. Using .NET 4.5...not sure if that matters.

Comment: Ok if I change <Setter Property="Header" to look like this, then they all 3 of them say "Collection": <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}, Path=Skins}"/>

Comment: Ok wait, I got the display working, but the command still doesn't fire. Hmmm. You still have the CommandParameter unchanged?

Comment: Yep. I left everything else the same.  I Copied all of your code from above and changed just that one line.  I'll add the rest of the context menu code so that you can see it in context, but it is the same as above.

Comment: hmmm yea that's exactly what I have now, but the breakpoint OnMenuItemClick in the ViewModel is never hit. unless I remove the <object> from the relay command and the (object selected) from the function. Then it works, but no Selected object. You didn't change anything in the ViewModel? Maybe something is different in my RelayCommand, I'll have to look at that.

Comment: I just noticed you don't have the using commands for mvvm on your ViewModel. Try adding: using GalaSoft.MvvmLight; and using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;

Comment: Ok wow I can see that a break point was hit in my Execute function of RelayCommandGeneric and the parameter is correct, "Skin Item 1", but for some reason it never makes it to the destination function.

Comment: Ok I got into it further and execution gets into WeakActionGeneric.cs inside MVVM-Light and calls the Execute(T parameter), but when it hits the check if(Method != null && ActionReference != null && actionTarger != null) it drops out of the function and never calls Method.Invoke(...). Also ActionReference = null and actionTarget = null.

Comment: Oh I don't have using MVVM statements because I baked MVVM-Light directly into the name-space of my project, that way I don't have any external dependencies, and nothing to maintain. So all I have to do is using ContextMenuTest_01.CommandBase and I get the RelayCommand because my project contains the MVVM-Light code for RelayCommand & WeakAction, etc...

Comment: I'm afraid I've run out of suggestions.  My code is the same as yours except for the things I mentioned.  I'm not familiar with the method you're using to bake it into your namespace, but maybe something is wrong there.  But I wouldn't know.  All I can say now is best of luck ;)

Comment: Found it! WeakAction constructor was missing a line of code between #endif compiler directives: ActionReference = new WeakReference(action.Target), once I added that in there it works perfect. That explains why the RelayCommand.cs file would work, but the RelayCommandGeneric would not. Thanks so much for all your time and effort! You have saved the day/week of an unemployed programmer! :-D

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  I just got out of the unemployed programmer space myself.  Best of luck with your job search.